# Is there a tool that lets me exaggerate audio levels?

Tags: software-rec, audio

It often happens that a movie I'm watching has audio loudness levels set too low. Since I use a typical laptop, I can't just go raise the volume level of my speakers.

I've raised all knobs offered by GNOME's Volume Control.

[image]

Are there tools out there that would allow me to take the loudness to beyond 100% level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mplayer` has `-softvol-max` option that allows to amplify loudness. VLC also by default allow you to raise volume up to 200%, but it can be changed in options.

Answer (score 5):

VLC lets you raise volume beyond what it calls 100%, and I assume it does that by an appropriate filter. Probably mplayer has one, too, but that involves reading the manpage, which you can do for yourself. ;)

So, short answer: look to your player program for a solution. (Though it's possible that you can globally configure something in ALSA.)

Comment: Haven't looked further, but VLC lets me raise volume up to 200%